# Can I mention a paper on my CV if it's accepted for a conference presentation but I don't present the paper?

Tags: paper-submission, conference, cv

My abstract was accepted for a paper presentation. However, I won't be able to attend the conference due to unavoidable circumstances.

Can I still mention this paper in my cv under conference presentation? If not, then how can I mention this in my CV?

Comment: Will it be printed in the proceedings or did you withdraw it?

Comment: No. It will not be printed and I didn't withdraw it. It's just that I won't be able to attend the conference on that date.

Comment: @AbdullahRayhan Do you have proceedings, to begin with?

Comment: To clarify, nobody at all will be presenting the paper?

Answer (score 1):

The culture is very different in different fields. Without further information, I have no idea whether your conferences are competitive publication venues (as e.g. in CS) or not.

If you want to list it on your CV, why not just write "accepted at X but not presented due to personal circumstances."